# C++ Win32Api GUI, I Am trying to display received screenshots on server from client. I am trying to create a Remote Desktop Viewer

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock2, win32gui

I am receiving those screenshots in WM_PAINT, and then save it to memory. The screenshots have around 8-10kB size. And I am trying to display those screenshots in a 15 FPS, but the problem is that its displaying sometimes glitched screenshots like this:
[the gray square with dots inside it, that should not be there, its covering the half of the screenshot :c ]

[image]
Image displayed like this, is like every second or third screenshot. I have no idea how to fix this im stuck a couple days at this.

Here is the server code (window procedure) where i am trying to display these screenshots

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ClientWndProc(HWND Chwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    std::vector<char> buffer(50000);

    switch (uMsg)
    {

    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
        ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
        GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
        SetTimer(Chwnd, SCREEN_TIMER, 1000/15, NULL);
        break;
    }
    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        if (wParam == SCREEN_TIMER)
        {
            SOCKET selectedSocket = clientSockets[itemIndex];
            auto it = std::find(clientSockets.begin(), clientSockets.end(), selectedSocket);
            
            send(selectedSocket, "capscr", strlen("capscr"), 0);

            InvalidateRect(Chwnd, NULL, TRUE);
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        SOCKET selectedSocket = clientSockets[itemIndex];
        auto it = std::find(clientSockets.begin(), clientSockets.end(), selectedSocket);

        if (it != clientSockets.end())
        {
            int bytesReceived = 0;
            int totalBytesReceived = 0;
            int expectedBytes = buffer.size();
            Sleep(1000/15);

            do
            {
                bytesReceived = recv(selectedSocket, buffer.data() + totalBytesReceived, buffer.size() - totalBytesReceived, 0);
                totalBytesReceived += bytesReceived;
            } while (totalBytesReceived < expectedBytes && bytesReceived > 0);

            //MessageBoxA(NULL, buffer.data(), "s", MB_OK);

            HGLOBAL hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GHND, expectedBytes);
            void* pData = GlobalLock(hGlobal);
            memcpy(pData, buffer.data(), buffer.size());
            GlobalUnlock(hGlobal);

            IStream* pStream = NULL;
            CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hGlobal, TRUE, &pStream);

            Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(pStream);
            Gdiplus::Status status = bitmap.GetLastStatus();

            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(Chwnd, &ps);

            int imgWidth = bitmap.GetWidth();
            int imgHeight = bitmap.GetHeight();

            Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);

            RECT clientRect;
            GetClientRect(Chwnd, &clientRect);

            graphics.DrawImage(&bitmap, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            EndPaint(Chwnd, &ps);
            GlobalFree(hGlobal);
        }
        
        break;
    }

    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return TRUE;

    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwndClient);
        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        DestroyWindow(hwndClient);
        return 0;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(Chwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

client code sending screenshots:

```
int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
    UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0)
        return -1;  // Failure

    pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
        return -1;  // Failure

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0)
        {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;  // Success
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return 0;
}

void shutdownGdiPlus()
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiPlusToken);
    gdiPlusToken = NULL;
}

bool initGdiPlusIfNeeded()
{
    // If already initialized then return true
    if (gdiPlusToken != NULL)
        return true;

    static Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiPlusStartupInput;


    return (success = GdiplusStartup(&gdiPlusToken, &gdiPlusStartupInput, NULL)) == Gdiplus::Status::Ok;
}

std::pair<ULONGLONG, char*> getScreenShotAsByteArray()
{
    if (!initGdiPlusIfNeeded())
        return {};

    IStream* iStream;
    HRESULT res = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &iStream);

    const HDC srcDC = ::GetDC(NULL);
    const int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    const int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    const HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(srcDC);
    const HBITMAP membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcDC, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, membit);
    BitBlt(memDC, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, srcDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Create a bitmap to store the previous screenshot
    HBITMAP prevBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcDC, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    HDC prevDC = CreateCompatibleDC(srcDC);
    SelectObject(prevDC, prevBitmap);

    // Get the size of the bitmaps in bytes
    BITMAP bmp;
    GetObject(prevBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);
    int prevBmpSize = bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmHeight * (bmp.bmBitsPixel / 8);
    GetObject(membit, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);
    int currBmpSize = bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmHeight * (bmp.bmBitsPixel / 8);

    // Allocate memory for the bitmap data
    char* prevBmpData = new char[prevBmpSize];
    char* currBmpData = new char[currBmpSize];

    // Get the raw pixel data of the bitmaps
    GetBitmapBits(prevBitmap, prevBmpSize, prevBmpData);
    GetBitmapBits(membit, currBmpSize, currBmpData);

    // Compare the bitmap data
    bool isDifferent = memcmp(prevBmpData, currBmpData, currBmpSize) != 0;

    // Free the allocated memory
    delete[] prevBmpData;
    delete[] currBmpData;

    // Check if the current screenshot is different from the previous screenshot
    if (isDifferent)
    {
        // Screenshot is different, take a new screenshot
        int newScreenWidth = 700;
        int newScreenHeight = 500;

        Gdiplus::Bitmap fullScreenBitmap(membit, NULL);
        Gdiplus::Bitmap newBitmap(newScreenWidth, newScreenHeight);
        Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(&newBitmap);
        graphics.DrawImage(&fullScreenBitmap, 0, 0, newScreenWidth, newScreenHeight);


        CLSID clsid;
        GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);

        ULONG quality = 0;
        EncoderParameters encoderParams;
        encoderParams.Count = 1;
        encoderParams.Parameter[0].Guid = EncoderQuality;
        encoderParams.Parameter[0].Type = EncoderParameterValueTypeLong;
        encoderParams.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues = 1;
        encoderParams.Parameter[0].Value = &quality;

        newBitmap.Save(iStream, &clsid, &encoderParams);

        ULARGE_INTEGER pos{ 0, 0 };
        const LARGE_INTEGER pos2{ 0, 0 };
        iStream->Seek(pos2, STREAM_SEEK_SET, &pos);

        ULONG bytesWritten = 0;
        STATSTG statstg;
        iStream->Stat(&statstg, STATFLAG_DEFAULT);
        const ULONGLONG bufferLen = statstg.cbSize.QuadPart;
        char* imageBuffer = new char[bufferLen];
        iStream->Read(imageBuffer, bufferLen, &bytesWritten);
        iStream->Release();

        DeleteObject(memDC);
        DeleteObject(membit);
        ::ReleaseDC(NULL, srcDC);

        std::pair<ULONGLONG, char*> result(bufferLen, imageBuffer);
        return result;
    }
    else
    {

        return {};
    }
}

void sendScreens() {
    if (clientsocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        // handle error, the socket is not valid or not connected
        return;
    }

        std::pair<ULONGLONG, char*> image = getScreenShotAsByteArray();
        ULONGLONG bufferLen = image.first;
        char* imageBuffer = image.second;

        int bytesSent = send(clientsocket, imageBuffer, bufferLen, 0);

        if(bytesSent < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        std::cout << "Sent Bytes: " << bytesSent << "\n";

        // wait for the desired interval before sending the next screenshot
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end = start + std::chrono::milliseconds(FPS);
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(end);

}
```

Comment: At a guess you're probably sending the data via TCP. If that's the case, you'll want to precede each screenshot with its length (or something on that order) so on the receiving end, you know how much to read. With TCP, what you transmit in a single call to `send` won't necessarily be received in a single call to `read`--you may need to issue multiple reads before you get all the data. You need to know how much data you expect to receive to know when to stop trying to read more data.